# SQL Drop Index on different Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, indexing

While trying to optimize SQL scripts, I was recommended to add indexes.

What is the easiest way to specify what Database the index should be on?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysindexes WHERE NAME = 'idx_TableA')  
  DROP INDEX TableA.idx_TableA 

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysindexes WHERE NAME = 'idx_TableB')  
  DROP INDEX TableB.idx_TableB
```

In the code above, TableA is in DB-A, and TableB is in DB-B.

I get the following error when I change `DROP INDEX TableA.idx_TableA`  to `DROP INDEX DB-A.dbo.TableA.idx_TableA`

```
Msg 166, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
'DROP INDEX' does not allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name.
```

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drop commands must use a USE statment with it if you are going to drop an index on a differet Database.

```
USE [DatabaseName]
Drop Index [IndexName]
```

Comment: SQL didn't like that inside the if statement either. Maybe my IF structure is incorrect.

Comment: You must do the USE before you execute the SQL to be run against the database.

Comment: I see now, the USE is on the outside of the IF statement. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

If you have permissions, another way is with EXEC('sql'). Also note that when querying sys.indexes, you need to prefix with the database name(s):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [DB-A].sys.indexes WHERE name = 'idx_TableA')
  EXEC('USE [DB-A]; DROP INDEX TableA.idx_TableA')

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [DB-B].sys.indexes WHERE name = 'idx_TableB')
  EXEC('USE [DB-B]; DROP INDEX TableB.idx_TableB')
```

Answer (score 6):

If you can not issue USE:

```
EXEC [DB-A].dbo.sp_executesql N'DROP INDEX TableA.idx_TableA'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the DROP INDEX ... ON syntax. That supports specifying a database and table name: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176118.aspx. The abbreviated syntax you were using is deprecated and "will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server".

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [DB-A].sys.indexes WHERE NAME = 'idx_TableA')  
  DROP INDEX [idx_TableA] ON [DB-A].dbo.[TableA]

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [DB-B].sys.indexes WHERE NAME = 'idx_TableB')  
  DROP INDEX [idx_TableB] ON [DB-B].dbo.[TableB]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might as well put the index name.

```
IF EXISTS (select 1 from sysindexes i, sysobjects o where o.name = 'idx_TableA'
and o.id = i.id and i.name='indexname')
     exec('use [db-a]; drop index idx_TableA.indexname')
     SELECT 'Drop the index'
else
     SELECT 'Index not found'
```